# Django: object disappearing from model

Tags: django

I have a simple django model with an integer field status:

```
from django.db import models

class MyObject(models.Model):
    dateDownloaded = models.DateField(null=True)
    dateShared = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
    sharedBy = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    sharedTo = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    status = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:  # First time saved
            self.status = 0
            self.token = get_random_string(length=32)
        super(MyObject, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I can add objects to my model and I have a simple helper that counts the number of created objects. Now I also have a call that does the following:

```
def resetStatus(request):
    myObjects = MyObject.objects.all()
    for myObject in myObjects:
        myObject.status = 0
        myObject.save()
    return HttpResponse("reset done")
```

Issue is, after calling this, from time to time all the objects from my database have disappeared. Maybe I have done something wrong with my objects in between but I have no idea what it could be. How can I go about debugging this ?

Comment: There's not really enough information here. Is this happening in production or development? Where is your site hosted? What are your database settings?

Comment: I am in development, server is running locally. Database settings look like
```DATABASES = {"default": {"ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
                         "NAME": "xxx",
                         "USER": "xxx",
                         "PASSWORD": "",
                         "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
                         "PORT": "5432"}}```

Comment: @vib If you open a `shell` (`./manage.py shell`) and do `print(MyObject.objects.all())` what do you get?

Comment: When my objects are there I get `<QuerySet [<MyObject: MyObject object>, <MyObject: MyObject object>]>` but I know that once they are not there anymore I have `<QuerySet []>`.

Comment: (one of) My problem is that I have a hard time reproducing this and finding what happens that make this happen. Also I have other objects in my database that are always there, so it seems to be related to this particular class, or what I do with it. However I have very little code touching those objects. Any idea of what kind of code could cause this could be very useful.

Comment: Basically the only other code I have which should be touching this object is doing something like:
```try: myObject = MyObject.objects.get(token=token) myObject.status = 1 myObject.save() except MyObject.DoesNotExist: pass```